# Green's formula for the Laplacian defined in a neighborhood of the surface

Tags: partial-differential-equations, curvature, greens-theorem

Source: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.00069.pdf

On page 4, it says that the surface Laplacian of a function $u$  (I will use different letters here) defined on a neighborhood of the boundary $\partial M$ is $$\Delta_M u= \Delta u - 2H \frac{\partial u}{\partial n}-\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial n^2}$$ where $H$ denotes the mean curvature of $S$ and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}=n \cdot\nabla u$.

My question(s):

1. What is $\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial n^2}?$
2. Multiplying the right side with a test function $v$ , then integrating and using Greens first identity I should get $$\int_M \nabla u \nabla v \, dx-2H \int_{\partial M}\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}v  \, ds - \int_{\partial M} ??? \, ds$$

What should the third integrand be?

Answer (score 1):

We have that
$$\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial\eta^2}={\rm Hess }u\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial\eta},\frac{\partial}{\partial\eta}\right).$$

Or, just
$$\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial\eta^2}=\eta\cdot\nabla(\eta\cdot\nabla u)$$

Comment: Thanks. So multiplying it with a test function $v$ can I express
$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial n^2}v$ in a simpler way?

Comment: I meant when integrating over it by using Green's identities or something